# Replace new line character in textArea field in Apex

Tags: apex, contact

In original `Contacts`, Tim Barr for example, I see that his address is written in the `Street` field like this :

```
2335 N. Michigan Avenue, Suite 1500
Chicago, IL 60601, USA
```

I tried to remove the new line of this `textArea` with several differents replace methods but nothing of them works :

```
street.replace('\n', ' ');
street.replace('\\n', ' ');
street.replace('\r\n', ' ');
street.replace('\\r\\n', ' ');
```

What's the correct syntax ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It depends on which character is used (that differs between operating systems). If you use these three (make sure the `\r\n` one is first) it should work:

```
street = street.replace('\r\n', ' ');
street = street.replace('\n', ' ');
street = street.replace('\r', ' ');
```

Comment: You mean I need to call this three methods on a row ? I used the methods I listed in my post one by one. I'll try.

Comment: If you run them all (with `\r\n` first) you're sure every possibility will be replaced. You can also use the `replaceAll()` function, that gets a regular expression as a first argument, so you can reduce this to one line. (see http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_apex250/Content/apex_methods_system_string.htm)

Answer (score 6):

Same answer as rael_kid, but in one regex:

```
replaceAll('\r\n|\n|\r',' ');
```

Answer (score 2):

I dont know previously it was supported or not, but now best way to achieve it is:

street = street.unescapeJava();